# Missing argument in Class

Tags: sql, php

i am quite new at Object oriented Programming and i can't manage to find why this practice project I have is wrong. It keeps giving me the folliwng error message:

"Warning: Missing argument 2 for Character::__construct(), called in C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject3\poo_bdd\connect_bdd.php on line 26 and defined in C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject3\poo_bdd\Character.class on line 13
 and same for argument 3 to 6

Definition of the class

```
<?php
class Character 
    {
        //attributs de la classe
        private $_id;
        private $_name;
        private $_strength;
        private $_damage;
        private $_level;
        private $_experience;

        //on définit le constructeur
        public function __construct($id, $name,$strength,$damage,$level,$experience) 
        {
            $this->setId($id);
            $this->setName($name);
            $this->setStrength($strength);
            $this->setDamage($damage);
            $this->setLevel($level);
            $this->setExperience($experience);
        }

        //hydratation 
        public function hydrate(array $data)
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            {
                $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);

                if (method_exists($this, $method))
                {
                    $this->$method($value);
                }
            }

            if(isset($data['id']))
            {
                $this->setId($data['id']);
            }
            if(isset($data['name']))
            {
                $this->setName($data['name']);
            }
            if(isset($data['strength']))
            {
                $this->setStrength($data['strength']);
            }
            if(isset($data['damage']))
            {
                $this->setDamage($data['damage']);
            }
            if(isset($data['level']))
            {
                $this->setLevel($data['level']);
            }
            if(isset($data['experience']))
            {
                $this->setExperience($data['experience']);
            }

        }

        //on définit les getters et setters
            //getters
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->_id;
        }
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->_name;
        }
        public function getStrength()
        {
            return $this->_strength;
        }
        public function getDamage()
        {
            return $this->_damage;
        }
        public function getLevel()
        {
            return $this->_level;
        }
        public function getExperience()
        {
            return $this->_experience;
        }

            // setters
        public function setId($id)
        {
              $this->_id = (int) $id;
        }

        public function setName($name)
        {
            if (is_string($name) && strlen($name) <= 30)
            {
                $this->_name = $name;
            }
        }

        public function setStrength($strength)
        {
            $this->_strength = $strength;
        }

        public function setDamage($damage)
        {
            $this->_damage = $damage;
        }

        public function setLevel($level)
        {
            $this->_level = $level;
        }

        public function setExperience($experience)
        {
            $this->_experience = $experience;
        }


     }
```

?>

And the php code:

```
<?php

require ('Character.class');

try
    {

            //connexion à la table blog_messages 
            $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test; charset=UTF-8', 'root', '', $pdo_options);
            $bdd->query('SET NAMES utf8');

            //sélection des 3 derniers billets
            $request = $bdd->query('SELECT id, name, strength, damage, level, experience FROM personnages');

            //affichage des billets
            while ($data = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    $character = new Character($data);

                    echo $character->getName(),' has a strength of',$character->getStrength();
                }
            //on termine le traitement de la requète
            $request->closeCursor();
   }
        catch (Exception $e)
            {
                die('Erreur: '.$e->getMessage());
            }
```

?>

The SQL tbale has 6 columns: id, name, strength, damage, level, experience.

If anybody has a clue, that would be great.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor accepts 6 arguments, whereas you are passing just one here:

```
$character = new Character($data);
```

If you want your constructor to accept a single associative array, use this as your `__construct` method:

```
    public function __construct($data) 
    {
        $this->setId($data["id"]);
        $this->setName($data["name"]);
        $this->setStrength($data["strength"]);
        $this->setDamage($data["damage"]);
        $this->setLevel($data["level"]);
        $this->setExperience($data["experience"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is displayed as your constructor takes 6 parameters but you only give him 1:

```
$character = new Character($data);
```

If you don't want to have the warning you either have to pass all 6 parameters (at least with '') to the constructor OR you have to use default values for the non mandatory parameters.

Comment: but in this oop practice, the point is to make the SQL table ...an object. So I put in $data, all the SQL table fields. i thought i would not need to state all 6 fields again this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor for the class Character is defined as:

```
__construct($id, $name,$strength,$damage,$level,$experience)
```

Yet you call it like:

```
$character = new Character($data);
```

Which looks more like your hydrate function?

Comment: Ok, maybe I made a big mistake. I just removed the __construct and left the hydrate function and it did at leats not give me an error: but it gave me : 'has a strength of has a strength of has a strength of ' . so at leats ther's no Error Message. But it did not get all the real figures and names i wanted to display by putting 'echo $character->getName(),' has a strength of',$character->getStrength();'

Comment: You could make the hydrate function static, and return a new class?

Then you would call it like `Character::hydrate($data);`. In the hydrate method you would create a new Character from the data array

Comment: @Mathieu You do not need to fiddle with the hydrate method at all. Just change the signature for `__construct`.

Comment: @Asad what do you mean by "change the signature"?

Comment: @Asad - that really depends on whether he also wants to use that as an alternative signature. Personally, I would keep the construct and create a Factory method for generating Characters.

Comment: @Asad I see. By the way, my program works even if i totally remove the hydrate function. So what's its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$character = new Character($data['id'],$data['name'],$data['strength'],$data['damage'],$data['level'],$data['experience']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your instantiation loop, use the [`extract`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)-function to extract the data into variables in the current scope:

```
//affichage des billets
while ($data = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'chr_');
   $character = new Character(
       $chr_id, $chr_name, $chr_str, 
       $chr_damage, $chr_level, $chr_experience
   );
   echo $character->getName(),' has a strength of',$character->getStrength();
}
```

Note that the extract-function is a bit magical and creates variables, so you need to know how `$data` looks to understand where the `$chr_`-variables are coming from.
A better alternative might be to create a factory, to encapsulate and visualize the data being extracted:

```
abstract class CharacterFactory
{
  /**
   * Creates a new Character-object from the $data provided
   * @param array $data Character data as an array
   * @return Character A Character object with its properties set from $data
   */
  public static function create (array $data)
  {
    $id = $data['id'];
    $name = $data['name'];
    $str = $data['str'];
    $damage = $data['damage'];
    $level = $data['level']
    $experience = $data['experience'];
    return new Character($id, $name, $str, $damage, $level, $experience);
  }
}

// In your loop:
//affichage des billets
while ($data = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   $character = CharacterFactory::create($data);
   echo $character->getName(),' has a strength of',$character->getStrength();
}
```